# devops: How to pull and run docker image from docker hub in a yaml script?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, yaml

On my local machine at the command line I run:

```
docker run \
  --rm --name MyImage \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=user \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myPass \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=myDB-db \
  -d \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  --mount "type=bind,source=C:\docker\postgres,destination=C:\pgsql\data"  \
  stellirin/postgres-windows
```

This starts up my postgres DB, and then I run my NUnit tests which call the DB running in the container with port mapped to  http://localhost:5432
This works fine locally.  I use continuation integration on Azure Devops and I would like to get this to work on azure.  Important point:  I do not want to use Azure Container Registry since I already have a docker hub account,
and the azure registry will add additional costs and overhead of copying images from DockerHub to the Azure registry.

Is this possible using yaml in a build pipeline (pulling from docker hub, building and running the container)?

Unfortunately it seems most of the information I find on Google requires Azure Container Registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a service connection in Project Settings -> Service connection first. Then choose the Docker Registry and input the information.

[image]

The following is the script about how to pull and run image from docker hub in YAML.

[image]

And you can edit it with Task assistant in Azure pipeline.

[image]

In addition, if you want to use the image in Azure, the ACR is required. Because ACR is the way which images can be stored on the Azure.